# This class requires automatic reference counting

Tags: irate

I am trying to add iRate from https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate to my app.

After adding file i get this error before even running the project.

```
#import "iRate.h"
#import <Availability.h>
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
#error This class requires automatic reference counting
#endif
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/amxPM.png

Comment: i found the solution... thanks

Comment: can you please share your solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in this issue in this link https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate. It is for ARC Compatibility.

> As of version 1.7, iRate requires ARC. If you wish to use iRate in a non-ARC project, just add the -fobjc-arc compiler flag to the iRate.m class. To do this, go to the Build Phases tab in your target settings, open the Compile Sources group, double-click iRate.m in the list and type -fobjc-arc into the popover.

If you wish to convert your whole project to ARC, comment out the
#error line in iRate.m, then run the Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC... tool in Xcode and make sure all files that you wish to use ARC for (including iRate.m) are checked.